# Filter a list of objects using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, generics, list

I have a list of custom objects. These objects have 2 datetime properties on them. I need to get a list of unique (ignore the time part) datetime objects from the two objects properties.

**Example**

I have 2 objects with 2 datetime properties:

```
object1.date1 = "01/01/2001 12:54"
object2.date1 = "01/02/2001 12:51"
object3.date1 = "01/01/2001 23:45"
object4.date1 = "01/02/2001 12:54"
object5.date1 = "01/01/2001 18:22"

object1.date2 = "09/01/2001 15:54"
object2.date2 = "09/02/2001 18:51"
object3.date2 = "08/01/2001 21:45"
object4.date2 = "08/02/2001 02:54"
object5.date2 = "07/01/2001 05:22"
```

These are stored in a list:

```
List<MyObject>() objList = new List<MyObject>()
objList.add(object1);
objList.add(object2);
```

I need to perform some LINQ on objList to produce a new List containing the following datetime objects in it:

```
01/01/2001 00:00
01/02/2001 00:00
09/01/2001 00:00
09/02/2001 00:00
08/01/2001 00:00
08/02/2001 00:00
07/01/2001 00:00
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like:

```
var newList = objList.Select(x => x.date1.Date)
                     .Concat(objList.Select(x => x.date2.Date))
                     .Distinct()
                     .ToList();
```

Does that look about right to you?

Answer (score 2):

```
var dates = objects
    .SelectMany(o => new[] { o.date1, o.date2 })
    .Select(d => DateTime.Parse(d).Date)
    .Distinct();
```

You can either use `Concat` and Jon suggested or `SelectMany` (which looks more natural to me).

Of course, ideally would be to encapsulate date parsing logic into `MyObject` class and expose `DateTime` properties rather than plain strings.